# Character encoding issues when printing a Jackson Json with Maven output

Tags: java, json, maven, jackson

Can anyone show me how ensure UTF-8 behavior, and avoid character encoding issues when creating a **json** using Jackson?

**// Code:**

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectNode root = mapper.createObjectNode();
root.put("Corinthians","Bi-campeão Mundial de Futebol");
System.out.println(root); // .toString()
```

**// Output:**

```
[exec:exec]
{"Corinthians":"Bi-campe?o Mundial de Futebol"}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe this depends on the supported charsets on your output device, ex. console.

Comment: Yes but I don't believe `Bi-campeão` is.

Comment: You're right, I'm running it as a Maven Project, and the Maven's output is not properly UTF-8 encoded. I've tested it as a simple project and the output was printed correctly.

Comment: Thank you! @Sotirios Delimanolis